# Can anyone tell me the best alternate to Geolayers addon for Aftereffects in blender

Tags: animation, texturing, compositing-nodes, animation-nodes, blend-files

I want to animate maps as it is like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=py4wZDoxMS8) created using Adobe After effects and Geolayers Plugin.

Maps with Malaysia highlighted

[image: Map Animation Image]

I have searched through Youtube but failed to find the right way to do it in blender.
What is the best alternate to do it in Blender? I can use Unreal also if needed or show any best alternate.